# How to colour vertices in a graph so no two neighboring vertices are the same colour in python?

Tags: python

I made a simple graph visualizer using networkx and matplotlib. But now I'm stuck trying to make it so the vertices are coloured in a way described in the title.

Here's how the code looks so far

```
G = nx.Graph()
G.graph["Name"] = "Moj Graf"

G.add_nodes_from([
        ("A", {}),
        ("B", {}),
        ("C", {}),
        ("D", {}),
        ("E", {})
        
        ])

G.add_edges_from([
        ("A", "C", {"weight": 1}),
        ("B", "C", {"weight": 3}),
        ("B", "D", {"weight": 2}),
        ("C", "D", {"weight": 4}),
        ("D", "E", {"weight": 1})
        ])

pos = {
       "A":(1,5),
       "B":(4,5),
       "C":(1,1),
       "D":(6,1),
       "E":(8,4)
       }

for u,v,d in G.edges(data=True):
    print(u,v)
    print(d)
    print("-------------------------")
    
for node in G.nodes:
    neighbors = [n for n in G.neighbors(node)]
    print(f"Neighbor({node})={neighbors}")
    print("-------------------------")

    
edge_labels = {(u,v):d["weight"] for u,v,d in G.edges(data=True)}

nx.draw(G, pos=pos, with_labels=True, node_color="black", node_size=1500,
        font_color="white", font_size=18, font_family="Times New Roman", font_weight="bold",
        edge_color="gray", width = 5)

nx.draw_networkx_edge_labels(G, pos=pos, edge_labels=edge_labels, label_pos=0.5,
                             font_size=20, font_family="Times New Roman", font_weight="bold")
plt.margins(0.2)
plt.show()
```

This for loop lists all the neighbors of every vertex. Maybe it can be used for colouring as well?

```
for node in G.nodes:
    neighbors = [n for n in G.neighbors(node)]
    print(f"Neighbor({node})={neighbors}")
    print("-------------------------")
```

Comment: What you are referring to is known as, [vertex coloring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_coloring#Vertex_coloring). I would look around online at the various algorithms and try implementing one.